# Running gradlew Corrupts Cache

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I have a kotlin project (compiling to java byte code) that works fine. I can build and run via IntelliJ. However as soon as I go to the command line and run `gradlew clean` or `gradlew build` in the project top level directory on the command line (windows), I get the following error:

```
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.<init>(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.kt:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:121)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:425)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:286)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError [in thread "RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1"]
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel.<clinit>(LanguageLevel.java:25)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.<init>(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.kt:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:121)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:425)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.parsing.ParseFileUtilsKt.classesFqNames(parseFileUtils.kt:46)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.parsing.ParseFileUtilsKt.classesFqNames(parseFileUtils.kt:35)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.getRemovedClassesChanges(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:362)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.calculateSourcesToCompileImpl(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:224)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.calculateSourcesToCompileImpl(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:169)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.calculateSourcesToCompileImpl(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.calculateSourcesToCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:171)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.sourcesToCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:163)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:107)
        ... 19 more
```

Once I do this, when I try to build via IntelliJ again, I get the same error. The only way to fix it is to delete the gradle cache.

It seems like a JDK version issue, but for the life of me I don't know what it is. I've tried switching versions and have the same issue.

Comment: ok... adding to `-Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=--illegal-access=permit` to  `org.gradle.jvmargs` in gradle.properties fixed it. I didn't want to add it there though, so running `gradlew clean -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=--illegal-access=permit` worked. After I did this once, I could then run `gradle clean` as normal. This is magic. I have no idea what any of this means.

Comment: The problem may be an outdated Kotlin version, please make sure you use Kotlin 1.7.0 in build.gradle.